# Wireless disabled problem

Tags: networking, wireless, lenovo

I had a problem with wifi on my Lenovo g50-30. wifi was disabled. I read on ubuntuforums that command:

```
sudo modprobe -r ideapad-laptop
sudo rfkill unlock all
rfkill list all
```

would help and it helped. I had been using my wifi and internet until I reboot my computer. Now I have to use this command all the time when I turn off my laptop. I'm looking for one good command which solves my wifi problem. Thank you and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

If you upgrade kernel to 3.19.0-26, you won't need to do anything. This bug has been fixed there.

I suggest removing `blacklist ideapad-laptop` from `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` if you did that.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist ideapad-laptop"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Reboot and tell us if your wireless is working.